# Background color on cart and checkout pages

Tags: wordpress, web, woocommerce, e-commerce, elementor

Im having trouble customizing the background of the tables that show in the cart and the checkout page of my site. I am using Woocommerce, Elementor and the basic elementor theme Hello.

I am in the CSS folder and I've been able to change the color of one row, but weirdly it has like a color intercalation, ones being lightly grey and the other ones white.

How can I change all products containing rows in both the cart and the checkout?

Here you can see what im talking about, you have to add at least two products to the cart...

https://comercialplazalareina.cl/?page_id=14

Answer (score 0):

Here, try adding this code to your theme's custom CSS

```
    body .woocommerce table.shop_table td {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Change the color from blue to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below Code End of style.css

For See Cart

```
.elementor-51 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5b22abc4 .elementor-button--view-cart {
background-color: #9fa0a0 !important;
}
```

For Finish Purchased

```
.elementor-51 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5b22abc4 .elementor-button--checkout {
background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Save It
Then Refresh Hard Refresh using ctrl+f5 button in fontend